# Apply max-height to an image while preserving width

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have an image in a table. Specifically a graph of profiling information that might be quite tall (one vertical pixel is data from one source, one horizontal pixel is one unit of time). I'ld like to specify a maximum height for the image and re-scale it vertically so that it can't extend too far down the page. But I want to preserve the width (the page can scale horizontally). i.e. I specifically want to change the aspect-ratio of the source image.

My html looks, vaguely like this and it mostly works.

```
<style>
img.capped {
  max-height : 500px;
  width : 100%;
}
</style>
...
<tr><th>Profile</th></tr>
<tr><td><img src=... class=capped></td></tr>
```

However if the image's width is less than the width of the string "Profile" my image gets scaled upward horizontally and vertically.

Is there a way, using CSS, to cap the vertical size of an image, resizing if necessary, but leave the width alone?

Comment: Maybe you could share a little more code or a live example. `max-height` will do what you are asking in a small-scale example: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/1adv3yga/

Comment: Use can also use your image as a CSS background + the rule `background-size: contain;`. The benefit is that it will adapt regardless of the container dimensions.

Comment: I think that you would need JavaScript for this. You would need to specify that the max-width of the image would be the original width, and you can't do that in CSS.

Comment: removing the width:100%; will keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: @BG101: He doesn't want to keep the aspect ratio. *"i.e. I specifically want to change the aspect-ratio"*

Comment: ahhh... it took me a few reads but I got there. As @Guffa recommends, JavaScript sounds the best way to 'resize'.

Comment: I was afraid I might need JS, I just wanted to see if I had missed anything. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can force the width by using `min-width`

```css
img {
  max-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" />
```

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, the expected result would be an image that is 350x100.

Comment: The width there for the min is of the containing TD, not the image. And isn't any more helpful than the width : 100%. Thanks though.